# sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost

Tags: linode

hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ubantu
hostname

### 127.0.0.1 localhost

I have kept lates code on linode
"sudo service apache2 restart"
sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost

I'm not able to trace out the issue. Please help me to find.

Comment: Does the output of the console say that it has restarted (you'll get something similar to `Service apache2              [ OK ]` if it has restarted properly. If not, have you looked at the logs?

Comment: root@127:/var/www/html# sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo: unable to resolve host 127.0.0.1localhost
AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for 127.0.0.1localhost
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Comment: it's working mistake i have done is in "hostname" file I have given "127.0.1.1 ubantu" it should be "ubantu" no need of "127.0.1.1".

Answer (score -1):

it's working mistake i have done is in "hostname" file I have given "127.0.1.1 ubantu" it should be "ubantu" no need of "127.0.1.1".